# Python 2.7: Cannot connect to SFTP server using Auth key

Tags: python-2.7, sftp

I have to connect to a remote sftp server to upload some files using python 2.7. i have been given a username, password and the authentication key file. when i execute this code:

```
srv= pysftp.Connection(host='54.172.33.121',username='xxx',password='xxx',private_key='c:\SFTPKey\hajjcoreit.ppk')
```

i get this error:

```
BadAuthenticationType: ('Bad authentication type', [u'publickey']) (allowed_types=[u'publickey'])
```

i can access the server through winSCP though.

Answer (score 0):

### Edits in your code

You probably have done something wrong with the hostname. As the proper syntax for pysftp is as

```
import pysftp
sftp = pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret')
#
# ... do sftp operations
#
sftp.close()    # close your connection to hostname
```

so now this is what you do,

```
srv=pysftp.Connection('sftp.54.172.33.121',username='xxx',password='xxx',private_key='c:\SFTPKey\hajjcoreit.ppk')
```

so you won't get any error.Also cross check with the filezilla that the link, uid and password are correct.

Comment: i tried adding sftp to the hostname. this is what i get now:

"raise ConnectionException(host, port)
ConnectionException: ('sftp.54.172.33.121', 22)"

Comment: @aliiqbal have you tried using the same username passkey and address in filezilla

Comment: @AliIqbal If you have an old version of pysftp it might be a problem try updating it using `pip install -u pysftp`